# Sails WebSocket connection to 'ws:

Tags: sockets, websocket, sails.js

I try to run server sails in production via command: `sails lift --prod` then I have error:

`VM448 production.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1337/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=1.2.1&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

When I run server in development environment via: `sails lift` that works well.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fix this problem I added links of site in production.js that locates in config/env/production.js.
I added links in onlyAllowOrigins that locates in sokets.

```
  onlyAllowOrigins: [
  'http://example.com',
  'https://myPage.com',
  'http://localhost:1337'
  // 'https://staging.example.com',
],
```

Comment: as the protocol is ws://localhost, how did this resolve for you?

Comment: I resolved it via setting correct address in onlyAllowOrigins. WebSockets will know where they will make a handshake.